# Moving or saving as .xlsm file breaks macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a .xlsm file which use a variable that gives the name of other spreadsheet using their index (it uses GET.WORKBOOK(1)). In order for this to work, I have to save the file as a .xslm file.
This file is saved on a onedrive and working but when saving a copy elsewhere, the macros are completely broken and I get #NAMES errors in my cells using it.
I tested it with a smaller file and I get exactly the same behavior.

This is the macro saved in the name manager.

`=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")`

I tested it in a small example: one excel .xslm file with one sheet, in one cell calling the variable should give me 'Sheet1'. Once I move this file and try to call this macro again I get #NAMES

Comment: Note that `GET.WORKBOOK` is an ancient Excel 4 relict that is only included for compatibility reasons and therefore should not be used anymore. What is your actual goal that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a list of all spreadsheets in the workbook in one summary page. This list is then used to have a table listing some parameters of all those sheets. Not sure if I am clear.

Comment: Why don't you write som VBA code then that generates this list in a worksheet?

Comment: Because I thought that what I was doing is the easiest and it was working. I have tried to find out why this is not working, but could not find anything yet, hence the question. I just want to know where it is coming from. If I can't do anything about it I will switch to VBA.

Comment: Actually for me it beeing an old Excel 4 relict is reason enough not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a short user defined function (in a module)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetWorkbookNameByIndex(Index As Long) As Variant
    Application.Volatile

    If Index <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        GetWorkbookNameByIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).Name
    Else
        GetWorkbookNameByIndex = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
End Function
```

So you can use it as a formula eg:

```
=GetWorkbookNameByIndex(A1)
```

And it will return the following:

[image]
*<sub>Image 1: Result of the function: If index is out of range it returns `#N/A` (=`#NV` in the image above because of German screensot).</sub>*

Note that the function has to be volatile, otherwise the formula won't update if a sheet name gets changed. Volatile functions are re-calculate on every calculation in the sheet and therefore come with a more heavy load on calculation. Volatile functions should not be used extensively or calculation will slow down significantly.

The fact that it is volatile will trigger an update if a sheet name gets changed or a sheed gets deleted or moved but actually **not if a new sheet is added**. Therefore you would need to either manuall re-calculate by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> or use the `NewSheet` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Same for the `NewChart` event if this is relevant for you.